# How to implement nonuniform block LBP in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have code that applies LBP to an image. After that, I need to divide the image into 3 x 3 blocks and decide whether each block is uniform or non-uniform.

```
function [M]=LBP(I)
%==========================================================================
Mc1=size(I,1);  %Height
Nc1=size(I,2);  %Width
      for i=2:Mc1-1   
      for j=2:Nc1-1 
         if (j<=Mc1-1)&& (i<=Nc1-1)
            J0=I(i,j);   
          I3(i-1,j-1)=I(i-1,j-1)>J0;  
           I3(i-1,j)=I(i-1,j)>J0;   
          I3(i-1,j+1)=I(i-1,j+1)>J0;  
            I3(i,j+1)=I(i,j+1)>J0;     
        I3(i+1,j+1)=I(i+1,j+1)>J0;    
          I3(i+1,j)=I(i+1,j)>J0;      
        I3(i+1,j-1)=I(i+1,j-1)>J0;     
         I3(i,j-1)=I(i,j-1)>J0;        
      I(i-1,j-1)=I3(i-1,j-1)*2^7+I3(i-1,j)*2^6+I3(i-1,j+1)*2^5+I3(i,j+1)*2^4+I3(i+1,j+1)*2^3+I3(i+1,j)*2^2+I3(i+1,j-1)*2^1+I3(i,j-1)*2^0; 
         end
end  
   end 
figure,imshow(uint8(I))
M=I;
```

My code is running but I need to modify it to detect whether the block is uniform or non-uniform.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What exactly is `LBP`?

Comment: LBP is local binary pattern.

Comment: How can implement LBP in nonuniform and compute blocks size 3*3

Comment: What is the criteria on whether a block is uniform or non-uniform?  I have no idea what local binary patterns are so some explanation would be nice.

Comment: Why no body answer to me???

Answer (score 0):

[Local binary Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_binary_patterns) or LBP is a powerful texture descriptor. It first divides the image into cells (e.g., a cell of 16x16 pixels). For each pixel in that cell, you compare its 8 neighbors with itself. If the neighbor is greater than the center pixel, record 1, else record 0. You get a binary number stream having 8 digits. Convert that to decimal. Take histogram over entire cell-> that is the LBP feature for a cell. Concatenate features for all the cells to get the feature vector for an entire image.

How to decide whether the image is uniform?

Well, that really depends on your criterion of uniformity.

1. Say, you want to distinguish a completely uniform image from other images. That's easy. Your LBP histogram should consist of all zeros.
2. Next, you have an image which has certain noisy pixels and gap between them is always more than 1 pixel. Detecting this is also easy, if the noisy pixel is more than all other pixels (which have the same value since you have that >1 pixel gap between two noisy pixels), then your LBP entry will be `11111111` or else it will be `00000000`. Easy enough to detect.

General case:

Here you need some formulation. First step would be to collect a database of uniform + non-uniform images (also called as training images). Then you extract LBP features for all of them. You perform training on those feature vectors and then classify the new images (also called as testing images) using the trained classifier. This should give you good results if your database has enough variation relative to your test set. You can use any classifier. I would recommend SVM but that's just an initial guess.

Comment: how can implementation this algorithm in matlab??

Comment: As you have implemented the LBP. After that, take that feature vector and compare it according to the guidelines I have written. You also have to mention your criterion for uniformity.

Comment: i am beginner to use matlab. can you help me to how implemented.

Comment: Is your image exactly uniform? Does it have only one color? You have to tell your criteria about uniformity.

Comment: I use Lena "gray color", but I don't now is it uniform or not we  need to check the image to see is it uniform or not.

Comment: What I am asking is whether you know if an image is uniform given that you know the image? In other words, is LENA image uniform?

Comment: At least answer the question I had asked above. If I give you a LENA image, would you say it is uniform or not? It is impossible that someone gives you answer if you don't know youq question properly. What are your uniformity criteria?

Comment: After apply LBP we have blocks from picture. I need to check is block uniform or not after that I will sort number inside block then compute mean and save index.

this what I need it.

thank you